# Controlling Text view layout with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following SwiftUI `Text` view:

```swift
Text("Hello, world. foo bar foobar foo hello world")
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
  .padding()
  .background(Color.red)
```

which renders like this (screenshots from Xcode preview, iPhone 13 Pro):

[image]

Adding a single character to the string causes the view to render as follows:

[image]

There is clearly space for "hello" on the first line, but the layout engine breaks the lines presumably where it feels is best. Is there any way to control this, to get the text to flow as far as it can on each line, within the constraints of the view?

Comment: I see no issue when I try your code.

Comment: I think it is not really layout but something like *styling*, in this case to avoid the only word in next line, ie. if you add, for example, word *more* at the end then *hello* goes back to first line. I don't think it can be controlled from SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use an overlay, with the `Text` having a fixed size horizontally. This will mean the `Text` will only take 1 line, and will not wrap to the next line because of the text being too long.

Code:

```
Text("")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Hello, world. foo bar foobar foo hello world more words etc etc")
            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
    }
    .padding()
    .background(Color.red)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]I did not find any problem on my end with your current code, it can take more characters not only single, however, but You can also use this `.lineLimit()` to control more flexibility:

```
see my output image:
`Text("Hello, world. foo bar foobar fooooooooo, hello world")
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
          .lineLimit(1)
          .padding()
          .background(Color.red)`[![output][1]][1]
```